A connection was successfully established with the server... In Excel but not Access
I've seen various similar questions to this but each of them relate to a total failure to connect, in my case I can connect via Access and used to be able to connect via Excel, but excel has stopped working, so presumably the issue is with an excel specific seting and not the connect per se. I'm running queries on SQL Server using a data connection through Excel and also via linked tables in Access. Up until the end of last week I could connect to Excel and Access and run queries with no issue. However when I tried to set up a new query in Excel I'm now getting

Microsoft SQL: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.

I can still read and write to the tables via MS Access but I cannot set up new excel conections and when I try to run establish query it also now throws the same error. I'm connecting to the db using my Windows credentials
I've had a quick surf around but cannot find any answers as to why it would affect 1 App but not another and I've looked in the MS trust centre for anything obvious. I'm sure the answer is out there, but with all things it's knowing the right question to ask!
